# nginx serving files from two different directories on one server

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have the following directory structure in my web server's filesystem:

```
-srv
 +---someDir
 |   +---mySite
 +---someOtherDir
     +---yourSite
```

Both, `mySite` and `yourSite`, shall be available from the same `nginx` webserver under different *directories* (path in the browser address bar), such as

http://myServer/mySite and

http://myServer/yourSite

I've tried to have one `server` entry in the configuration with two `location` blocks (with varying settings), but none delivered the expected result - neither with a "server level" root entry, not without. For example (nginx.conf):

```
http {
    ...
    server {
        root /srv/;
        location = /mySite {
            root /srv/someDir/mySite/;
    }
}
```

As I said, all with different combinations of `root` and also `try_files` etc.

I thought it should be possible to have something like

```
...
server {
    location = /mySite {
        root /srv/someDir/mySite/;
    }

    location = /yourSite {
        root /srv/someDir/yourSite/;
    }
}
```

Where is my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is where you have total control over the filesystem and URI name spaces, so that the application in `/path/to/root/foo/index.html` is accessible using the URI `/foo/` and the application in `/path/to/root/bar/index.html` is accessible using the URI `/bar/`.

In this case, no `location` blocks are necessary, and the value of `root` is `/path/to/root` because the pathname of the file is constructed by concatenating this value with the URI. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.

For example:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    root /path/to/root;
}
```

The above server block will fine application foo at `http://example.com/foo/` and application bar at `http://example.com/bar/`.

---

In the case where the top level directory element has a different name to the top level URI element, you will need to use an `alias` directive within a `location` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

For example:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;

    location /foo/ {
        alias /path/to/foos/directory/;
    }
    location /bar/ {
        alias /path/to/bars/directory/;
    }
}
```

Both the `location` value and the `alias` value should end with `/`, or neither end with `/`.

Note that the `location` directive is used **without** the `=` operator, which is only used to match a single URI. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: I don't understand the first example as I can only have one `root` entry in the `server` block, how would this work with two applications?

What did work, though, was the second example (after tweaking the `base href` element in my html as well). Thank you for providing me with a solution :-)

Comment: If the two applications share the same common root, you only need one `root` statement, which points to the parent directory.